# Forms and form fields in HTML

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to make an automated absent management software for an academic institute. Being just a rookie i'm stuck at this point. I want the name of a teacher to not appear in the drop down lists against the remaining absent teachers for a particular period once he has been selected to substitute for a staff. This I want without hitting the final submit button in the end. I.e.- before actually storing into actual database.

The name Sujata Das shouldn't appear for Aditi Bhatia for period 3.

[image]

Here's the code that I have used to populate the drop down lists..

```
       //------------------FOLLOWING MODULE LISTS DOWN THE NAME OF THE TEACHERS WHO ARE PRESENT AS WELL AS FREE FOR A PARTICULAR PERIOD OF THE ABSENT TEACHER----------------


$a=1;
$r5 = mysql_query("SELECT class FROM timetable WHERE empno={$row['empno']} and period=$a");
while($r6=mysql_fetch_array($r5,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

    if($r6['class']!=0)
    {   
        echo "<td>";

        echo "<select name='name' id='name'>";
         echo "<option selected disabled hidden value=''></option>";

        $r5=mysql_query("select m.name,m.empno,t.empno, t.attend,t.date,s.empno,s.period,s.class from master m,tattend t,timetable s where (m.empno=t.empno and m.empno=s.empno and t.attend=0 and t.date='$d' and s.period=$a and s.class=0)");
        while($r6=mysql_fetch_array($r5,MYSQL_ASSOC))
        echo "<option value='" . $r6['name'] . "'>" . $r6['name'] . "</option>";
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</td>";
    }
    else echo "<td></td>";

++$a;
$r5 =mysql_query("SELECT class FROM timetable WHERE empno={$row['empno']} and period=$a");
}
echo "</tr><tr></tr>";
```

Comment: Can you Provide some sort of code as how you are collecting data for substitute Teacher?

Comment: Show what you've tried and be specific about where you're getting an error / issue.

Comment: If you want to do something on the client side, without having to send data to the server, you'll need JavaScript. We can't give you any specific suggestions without code, though.

Comment: If you want a teacher to only appear once in the timetable (e.g. once selected, cannot be selected again), then you will need to use JS.

Comment: I haven't required java script uptill now. So can anyone please tell me what topic should I refer to in JS so that the rest of the form fields get customized according to an option selected in any one of those field??